# Kinesis Firehose lambda transformation

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws-lambda

I have the following lambda function as part of Kinesis firehose record transformation which transforms msgpack record from the kinesis input stream to json.

Lambda Runtime: python 3.6

```
from __future__ import print_function

import base64
import msgpack
import json
print('Loading function')


def lambda_handler(event, context):
  output = []

  for record in event['records']:
    payload = msgpack.unpackb(base64.b64decode(record['data']), raw=False)

    # Do custom processing on the payload here
    output_record = {
        'recordId': record['recordId'],
        'result': 'Ok',
        'data': json.dumps(payload, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8')
    }
    output.append(output_record)

  print('Successfully processed {} records.'.format(len(event['records'])))
  return {'records': output}
```

But lambda throwing the following error:

```
An error occurred during JSON serialization of response: b'
{
   "id": "d23fd47f-3a62-4383-bcb3-abdb913ea572",
   "timestamp": 1526358140730,
   "message": "Hello World"
}
' is not JSON serializable
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
**kw).encode(obj)
File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
 return _iterencode(o, 0)
File "/var/runtime/awslambda/bootstrap.py", line 110, in 
decimal_serializer
raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue.

Here is the code which worked for me.

```
from __future__ import print_function

import base64
import msgpack
import json

print('Loading function')


def lambda_handler(event, context):
  output = []

  for record in event['records']:
    payload = msgpack.unpackb(base64.b64decode(record['data']), raw=False)

    # Do custom processing on the payload here
    output_record = {
       'recordId': record['recordId'],
       'result': 'Ok',
       'data': base64.b64encode(json.dumps(payload).encode('utf-8') + b'\n').decode('utf-8')
    }
    output.append(output_record)

  print('Successfully processed {} records.'.format(len(event['records'])))
  return {'records': output}
```

Comment: When I return my records similar to you have, I get errors saying `One or more record Ids were not returned. Ensure that the Lambda function returns all received record Ids` however when I print my `output` list, it shows me my 200 records. All my other stuff works fine as I have some other logic that does stuff within a try-except. But for some reason it writes this for each of the 200 entries.

Comment: The last two lines need to be de-indented, as they need to be outside the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to fix it this way:

```
import base64
import gzip
import io
import json
import zlib
def cloudwatch_handler(event, context):
  output = []
  for record in event['records']:
    compressed_payload = base64.b64decode(record['data'])
    uncompressed_payload = gzip.decompress(compressed_payload)
    print('uncompressed_payload',uncompressed_payload)
    payload = json.loads(uncompressed_payload)
    output_record = {
        'recordId': record['recordId'],
        'result': 'Ok',
        'data': base64.b64encode(json.dumps(payload).encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')
    }
    output.append(output_record)
  print('Successfully processed {} records.'.format(len(event['records'])))
  return {'records': output}
```

This solution doesn't require you to include modules from outside python like msgpack

Answer (score 0):

I have a go version lambda function doing the transforming job.

https://github.com/hixichen/golang_lamda_decode_protobuf_firehose