# Is there a way to connect Kinesis Firehose to Lambda and then to S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am creating an architecture that takes data from amazon connect --> kinesis data streams --> kinesis firehose --> raw data S3 bucket and lambda for processing --> processed data S3 bucket. I have enabled record pre-processing via the lambda instance in my firehose configuration but it does not show as the trigger for the function. I also am confused how to send the processed data to S3 from Lambda, as that is not a default option. I know I need to write some sort of code to do so but am struggling.. please help

does this make sense? let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: Yes, that is basically what firehose does: it optionally invokes a transformation lambda with the records in configurable batches and writes the result to s3 in separately configurable batches.

Comment: @luk2302 yes i understand that part, but i'm stuck because my data is not going to lambda and i dont know how to then send it from lambda to S3.

Comment: The lambda does not write to S3, Firehose does. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/amazon-kinesis-firehose-data-transformation-with-aws-lambda/ https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/data-transformation.html and maybe firehose cannot find / invoke the lambda function, in that case firehose writes to s3 under an error prefix which is once again configurable.

Comment: @abby Please Edit your question to tell us more about your actual configuration, the services you are using (is it Kinesis, or Kinesis Firehose), and what you are wanting to accomplish. More information, please.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Just added some more info, please let me know if you can help

Comment: Why are you sending via Kinesis Data Streams? It appears that Amazon Connect can go directly to Kinesis Firehose. When a Lambda function is used as part of an Amazon Kinesis Data Firehose Data Transformation, I think Firehose calls the function directly -- it probably doesn't show up as a Trigger, since Firehose calls it directly and then takes the output and uses it in the flow. Firehose should send the resulting records to S3 if that's where you have told it to send the data. If no data is getting to S3, try without the Lambda function first to confirm that the data is flowing.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yes, from connect it does go straight to the firehose--you're right. in terms of the trigger aspect, thank you for clarifying. now, for the s3 part, do you mean when i configure the data to go to s3 in the firehose stream? because i want it to go *processed* from lambda to s3 and am not getting anything in my bucket.

Comment: The normal flow is Firehose --> S3. An AWS Lambda function "Data Transformation" can be configured within Firehose that can look at the records and decide whether to allow a record, modify it or drop it. First, do it without the Lambda function to confirm that records are flowing, then add the Lambda function that returns a `result` field. See an example here: [amazon web services - AWS lambda transformation to firehose: Python - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63212397/aws-lambda-transformation-to-firehose-python)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yes without the lambda it works. when i test demo data it shows up in my bucket so that's why i'm assuming the issue is with lambda and not firehose. Thank you for sharing those resources, ill definitely take a look. Hopefully they will elaborate on what you mentioned regarding firehose being able to decide what records/modifications it will allow.

Comment: See also: [Amazon Kinesis Data Firehose Data Transformation - Amazon Kinesis Data Firehose](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/data-transformation.html)